# Why does my USB 3.1 Gen 1 only transfer at 300-340MB/s and not 640MB/s?

Tags: windows-10, usb, ssd

I recently bought a Samsung T7 SSD that supports USB 10GBbit. My PC only supports the original USB 3.0 specification of 5GBit. 5GBit should get my 640MByte/s, but I'm getting less than half that.

Both the external SSD and internal SSD support read/write speeds over 1,000MByte/s. Despite all this bandwidth, I consistently only read from the device at 340MB/s and write to the device at 300MB/s

What is the source of the speed bottleneck and how might I diagnose it?

Comment: I can not definitively tell you the answer.  What I can tell you is that on some specific mobo brands, I can only get half throughput (or less) via USB3.  On other brands, it SCREAMS.  I can only assume driver.. but I don't know.  On the "bad ones", I can see that it starts out fast.. then BARFS down to bytes-per-second looking at the progress dialog graph.  In one case, HP blamed it on Microsoft and Microsoft blamed it on HP so who knows.

Comment: Your performance is what I would expect out of USB 3.2 GEN 1 (USB 3.2 GEN 1 is AKA USB 3.1 GEN 1 and USB 3.0).  The device itself supports "up to" 1050MB/s but only when connected to a USB 3.2 GEN 2 port.

Answer (score 0):

There is overhead on the USB, so I would not expect it over 500 megabytes per second for a 5 GBit/s USB.

Possible causes of slowdown:

- Other devices on the same USB bus?
- I have experienced USB 3.0 slowdowns from outdated/bad drivers (Win 10).
- Third party USB C cables that are missing the pull-up resistor, which causes it to slow down.
- Damaged cable.

I don't think your read number is unreasonable.